# HTTP 500 Deploying Elixir/Phoenix to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm having trouble with the elixir/phoenix config that I need for a deployment to AWS/Elastic Beanstalk. (Following the guide found here: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/deploying-elixir-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk-with-docker - my Dockerfile looks similar except for updated libraries).

I can run in `eb local run`, but am having trouble pushing to production.

However, when I try and deploy to EB, I get the following warning, and it crashes:

```
Environment health has transitioned from Degraded to Severe. 
100.0 % of the requests are failing with HTTP 5xx. 
Command failed on all instances. 
Incorrect application version found on all instances. Expected version "app-8412-171116_115503" (deployment 5). 
ELB processes are not healthy on all instances. 
100.0 % of the requests to the ELB are erroring with HTTP 4xx. 
Insufficient request rate (0.5 requests/min) to determine application health (5 minutes ago). 
ELB health is failing or not available for all instances.
```

I was wondering if someone could let me know if my configs look right.

I've been trying a bunch of things, but I think I've gotten confused, as I'm just guessing at this point.

***config.exs***

```
use Mix.Config

config :newsly,
  ecto_repos: [Newsly.Repo]

config :logger, :console,
  format: "$time $metadata[$level] $message\n",
  metadata: [:request_id]

import_config "#{Mix.env}.exs"
```

***prod.exs***

```
use Mix.Config

config :logger, :console, format: "[$level] $message\n"

config :phoenix, :stacktrace_depth, 5


import_config "prod.secret.exs"
```

***prod.secret.exs***

```
use Mix.Config

config :ex_aws,
  access_key_id: System.get_env("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"),
  secret_access_key: System.get_env("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"),
  bucket_name: System.get_env("BUCKET_NAME"),
  s3: [
   scheme: "https://",
   host: System.get_env("BUCKET_NAME"),
   region: "us-west-2"
  ]

config :newsly, Newsly.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  username: System.get_env("USERNAME"),
  password: System.get_env("PASSWORD"),
  database: System.get_env("DATABASE"),
  hostname: System.get_env("DBHOST"),
  # sometimes hostname is db (like in the docker-compose method - play with this one)
  pool_size: 10


config :newsly, Newsly.Endpoint,
  http: [port: 4000],
  debug_errors: true,
  code_reloader: false,
  url: [scheme: "http", host: System.get_env("HOST"), port: 4000],
  secret_key_base: System.get_env("SECRET_KEY_BASE"),
  pubsub: [adapter: Phoenix.PubSub.PG2, pool_size: 5, name: Newsly.PubSub],
  check_origin: false,
  watchers: [node: ["node_modules/brunch/bin/brunch", "watch", "--stdin",
                    cd: Path.expand("../", __DIR__)]]
```

And in my Dockerfile I set my environment variables like the following;

```
ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=nottelling
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=nottelling
ENV BUCKET_NAME=s3 storage bucket (not eb related)
ENV SECRET_KEY_BASE=nottelling
ENV HOST=host name of my eb instance im uploading to
ENV DBHOST=AWS rds host that holds postgres
ENV USERNAME=nottelling
ENV PASSWORD=nottelling
```

My health report on the instance fails to red with the following warning:

```
Environment health has transitioned from Warning to Severe. 100.0 % of the requests are failing with HTTP 5xx. ELB processes are not healthy on all instances. ELB health is failing or not available for all instances.
```

NGINX seems to be choking with the lines

```
2017/11/16 17:59:46 [error] 28815#0: *99 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.20.108, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.2:4000/", host: "172.31.38.244"
```

in nginx logs.

If I look at eb-activity log I have

```
duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy.conf:11
```

which seems to be killing nginx

```
[2017-11-16T18:02:33.927Z] INFO  [29355] - [Application update app-8412-171116_115503@5/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/01flip.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  nginx: [warn] duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy.conf:11
  Stopping nginx: [  OK  ]
  Starting nginx: nginx: [warn] duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy.conf:11
  [  OK  ]
  iptables: Saving firewall rules to /etc/sysconfig/iptables: [  OK  ]
  Stopping current app container: e0161742ee69...
  Error response from daemon: No such image: aws_beanstalk/current-app:latest
  Making STAGING app container current...
  Untagged: aws_beanstalk/staging-app:latest
  eb-docker start/running, process 1398
  Docker container e25f2b562f4f is running aws_beanstalk/current-app.
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:

Digging through the logs for nginx I found

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default        "upgrade";
    ""            "";
}

server {
    listen 80;

    gzip on;
        gzip_comp_level 4;
        gzip_types text/html text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
        set $year $1;
        set $month $2;
        set $day $3;
        set $hour $4;
    }
    access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;

    access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass            http://docker;
        proxy_http_version    1.1;

        proxy_set_header    Connection            $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade                $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

So,

```
duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy.conf:11
```

Seems to be referring to this line:

```
gzip_types text/html text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
```

But at this point I would find it surprising if nginx was choking simply because it defines `text/html` twice. So now I'm not sure....

EDIT EDIT:
I should mention that my nginx/error.logs look like the following (the last lines repeat ad-infinum):

```
2017/11/16 17:19:22 [warn] 18445#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy.conf:11
2017/11/16 17:19:22 [warn] 18460#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy.conf:11
2017/11/16 17:20:06 [error] 18467#0: *11 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.32.139, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.2:4000/", host: "172.31.38.244"
2017/11/16 17:20:15 [error] 18467#0: *13 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.20.108, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.2:4000/", host: "172.31.38.244"
2017/11/16 17:20:21 [error] 18467#0: *15 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.32.139, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.2:4000/", host: "172.31.38.244"
2017/11/16 17:20:30 [error] 18467#0: *17 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.20.108, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream:
```

***THIS IS THE HEART OF THE PROBLEM***

NGINX fundamentally cant connect the entrypoint to the application and I don't know why!

UPDATE:

Using Kevin Johnson's advice I successfully pushed up to AWS ECR my Dockerfile and it compiled correctly when I `eb deploy`'ed my application with a good `Dockerrun.aws.json`. This is in fact a preferred way to do this. **HOWEVER**, I still get the same error! I do not know what is going on, but I think I can safely say that my Dockerfile successfully compiles.

I think there is something broken in AWS and I'm not sure what.

UPDATE

Problem is related to a NGINX routing issue. More information here in a clean question: [How Do I modify NGINX routing on Elastic Beanstalk AWS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47361467/how-do-i-modify-nginx-routing-on-elastic-beanstalk-aws)

Comment: Endpoint doesn't work with that `url: [scheme: "http", host: System.get_env("HOST"), port: 4000]`. Try to run it only with specified port.

Comment: I'm sorry PatNowak I don't understand what you are saying. `url: [scheme: "http", host: System.get_env("HOST"), port: 4000]` is being run with a specified port. Port 4000 which is written right there. Huh?

Comment: I mean: apply only `url: [port: 4000]`. I'm quite sure that there's issue with `host` on elastic beanstalk and I'm not so sure whether `scheme` works as well.

Comment: ok ill try it and get back to you

Comment: @PatNowak - I've changed the line you specified to `url: [port: 4000]` and I get `100.0 % of the requests are failing with HTTP 5xx.
ELB processes are not healthy on all instances.
ELB health is failing or not available for all instances.` If I ssh into the eb instance the docker container fails to boot and I still have the nginx  error.

Comment: So, I've just added the code from https://robots.thoughtbot.com/deploying-elixir-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk-with-docker to a fresh hello world boilerplate. Pushing to AWS gives the same timeout error. I'm not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: This is not related to your issue at all, but once everything is working, you should look into EC2 Instance Profile as an alternative to specifying your aws credentials inside your Docker container as env variables. `ex_aws` has support for it. Basically, aws will periodically rotate credentials for your instance. If you find it too challenging, then move your env variables to EB config under Software Configuration - Environment Variables in the console

Answer (score 1):

I highly suspect that the issue you are dealing with is either:

1. Your `Dockerrun.aws.config` file points to a non existing docker image on `ECS Repository`. This is indicated by the error message:
   `Error response from daemon: No such image: aws_beanstalk/current-app:latest
   Making STAGING app container current...`
   When EB fails to replace the instance with the latest configuration, it will resort back to the old one, which could be the `Hello World` app of AWS that you may have leveraged in setting up EB. That container does not have a web service running on port 4000, whereas your `Dockerrun.aws.config` specifies port 4000.
   (I would be surprised though that your `Dockerrun.aws.config` does not get replaced as well by EB to previous working version)
   So check `Dockerrun.aws.config` and ensure that the image endpoint mentioned therein actually exists. Try pulling it locally and run it accordingly. First clean up your local environment of all images and running docker containers if need be.
2. Your application running within docker immediately crashes upon startup. Again, EB will detect this and replaces the crashed container with the previous container which again does not have port `4000` open.

Comment: Well, as I said above `eb local run` works, so I don't think that the app is crashing. I don't really understand 1. - I have not done this (I assume you mean the `ECR Repository`), but I don't understand why it is necessary. I am pushing my dockerfile & my dockerrun, so shouldn't AWS build from what I supply? Why is an external docker repository necessary? I will go through the steps and see if that has solved my problem, but it has me very confused.

Comment: Also, I haven't heard of `Dockerrun.aws.config`. It is not a file I supply, I only push up the `Dockerrun.aws.json` according to the tutorial I linked. Should it be a file in the `eb ssh repo`? If so, where is it located? I cannot find reference to it online.

Comment: When you do an `eb deploy`, the only asset that you need to care about in a EB Docker Deployment Env is the file `Dockerrun.aws.config`. That is the configuration file that EB will look into to do all that is necessary. This config file will contain which repo the image can be downloaded from(dockerhub, AWS ECR) as well as all your port settings. There is no need to upload your  bare code to EB. So what you can do is, create a separate folder for deployment purposes, go inside it and do eb config, set everything, then in the root of that folder you add `Dockerrun.aws.config`.

Comment: To answer your other question, yes you can also upload a Dockerfile, but `Dockerrun.aws.json`(not `Dockerrun.aws.config`, my error) is the main one that is required. If you specify within `Dockerrun.aws.json` the location of the remote docker repo you push your builded elixir container to, then there is no need for Dockerfile etc.

Comment: can you provide a link to something mentioning `Dockerrun.aws.config`? I'm sorry to be obtuse, but every website I have gone to has mentioned that you need to use a `Dockerfile` and a `Dockerrun.aws.json`. And none of them mention uploading the Image to a repository, the assumption has been that AWS will build the image from the Dockerfile (and my eb-activity.logs are showing it does). If you have an alternative method I'd be interested, but I need a little more to go on. My: Dockerfile: https://hastebin.com/momelofavo.nginx & Dockerrun: https://hastebin.com/umivigutow.json

Comment: `A Dockerrun.aws.json file describes how to deploy a Docker container as an Elastic Beanstalk application. This JSON file is specific to Elastic Beanstalk. If your application runs on an image that is available in a hosted repository, you can specify the image in a Dockerrun.aws.json file and omit the Dockerfile.` http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_image.html

Comment: Oh....ok just saw that. Well, let me modify my question - Is adding a name in my Dockerrun shadowing my Dockerfile and erroneously telling AWS to search for an image that doesn't exist. Is it safe to remove that name, or does it matter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159253/discussion-between-kevin-johnson-and-peter-weyand).

Comment: Just wanted to give you a heads up that this didn't solve the problem. But thanks for the suggestion anyway, as it seems to be the preferred solution for image stability.