# How Do I modify NGINX routing on Elastic Beanstalk AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

So I had a *very* long post related to deployment of an elixir app to Elastic Beanstalk (here: [HTTP 500 Deploying Elixir/Phoenix to AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47336985/http-500-deploying-elixir-phoenix-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk)).

I've finally boiled the problem to my NGINX being misconfigured to route traffic. It's posting this:

```
2017/11/18 00:52:45 [error] 2811#0: *15 connect() failed (113: No route to host) 
while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.25.36, server: ,
request: "GET / HTTP/1.1",
upstream: "http://172.17.0.2:4000/", host: "172.31.17.239"
```

I've looked online for possible solutions and found (I also need to add the ability to use websockets that this bit of code looks closest: https://scopestar.com/blog/aws/elasticbeanstalk/websockets/2016/10/21/enable-websockets-on-elasticbeanstalk-nginx-proxy.html

I've gotten the following so far - it deletes the previous config, writes a new one with websockets.

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/01_nginx_websocket.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      upstream nodejs {
        server 127.0.0.1:8081;
        keepalive 256;
      }

      server {
        listen 8080;

        if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
            set $year $1;
            set $month $2;
            set $day $3;
            set $hour $4;
        }
        access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;


        location / {
          proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header  Host  $host;
          proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

      gzip on;
      gzip_comp_level 4;
      gzip_types text/html text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

      }

container_commands:
 removeconfig:
    command: "rm -f /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#conf.d#00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf"
```

But I'm a little stuck on how I do the actual **routing**. Is there a good example of how to change the upstream and server routes so that they handshake correctly and solve the error I'm getting?

EDIT:

This website: https://dennisreimann.de/articles/phoenix-nginx-config.html

Suggested I do something along the lines of take my image on my Dockerfile and route all traffic to localhost:myport and then route that to AWSEB:80, which seemed straightforward enough.

I made something that looks like the following in my .ebextensions as .conf:

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/01_nginx_websocket.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      upstream nodejs {
        server localhost:4000;
        keepalive 256;
      }

      server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name newslyproduction3.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com;

        if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
            set $year $1;
            set $month $2;
            set $day $3;
            set $hour $4;
        }
        access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;


        location / {
          proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header  Host  $host;
          proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

      gzip on;
      gzip_comp_level 4;
      gzip_types text/html text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

      }

container_commands:
 removeconfig:
    command: "rm -f /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#conf.d#00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf"
```

However, this gives different errors and I'm not sure if I'm getting closer or moving farther away.

```
INFO: Successfully built aws_beanstalk/staging-app
ERROR: Failed to start nginx, abort deployment
ERROR: [Instance: i-0c48e103c226ca0a9] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...enabled/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy.conf:11
nginx: [emerg] could not build server_names_hash, you should increase server_names_hash_bucket_size: 64
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Failed to start nginx, abort deployment.
```

This post [Nginx getting error with specific domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895933/nginx-getting-error-with-specific-domain-name) suggests that I need to increase the name size in the http block, but I don't know where that is in the nginx of AWS EB.

EDIT:

Following code snippets that I found from here https://dennisreimann.de/articles/phoenix-nginx-config.html (and elsewhere I remade my file to look like the following):

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/01_nginx_websocket.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      upstream nodejs {
        server localhost:4000;
        keepalive 256;
      }

      # log_format healthd '$msec"$uri"'
      #          '$status"$request_time"$upstream_response_time"'
      #          '$http_x_forwarded_for';

      server {
        listen 80;
        server_name _ localhost;

        if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
            set $year $1;
            set $month $2;
            set $day $3;
            set $hour $4;
        }

        access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;

        access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log;


        location / {
          proxy_pass http://newslyproduction3.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header  Host  $host;
          proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

      gzip on;
      gzip_comp_level 4;
      gzip_types text/html text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

      }

container_commands:
 removeconfig:
    command: "rm -f /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#conf.d#00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf"
```

So now it is referencing localhost on the docker machine and routing to my instance. Or so I thought.

This uploads ok, but then fails with the following logs for NGINX:

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/access.log
-------------------------------------
172.31.35.70 - - [18/Nov/2017:04:12:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 463 0 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.6.206 - - [18/Nov/2017:04:12:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 463 0 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.35.70 - - [18/Nov/2017:04:12:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 463 0 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.6.206 - - [18/Nov/2017:04:12:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 463 0 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
```

and my app starts powercycling

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/20c6293b969d-stdouterr.log
-------------------------------------

** (exit) exited in: :gen_server.call(#PID<0.221.0>, {:checkout, #Reference<0.0.1.3329>, true, :infinity}, 5000)
    ** (EXIT) time out
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection/poolboy.ex:112: DBConnection.Poolboy.checkout/3
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:920: DBConnection.checkout/2
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:742: DBConnection.run/3
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:1133: DBConnection.run_meter/3
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:584: DBConnection.prepare_execute/4

** (exit) exited in: :gen_server.call(#PID<0.221.0>, {:checkout, #Reference<0.0.1.3329>, true, :infinity}, 5000)
    ** (EXIT) time out
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection/poolboy.ex:112: DBConnection.Poolboy.checkout/3
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:920: DBConnection.checkout/2
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:742: DBConnection.run/3
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:1133: DBConnection.run_meter/3
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:584: DBConnection.prepare_execute/4
```

The dockerfile compiles and it runs locally (with non-production configs) and I have the production configs and dockerfile that the tutorial I am working with says to have (https://robots.thoughtbot.com/deploying-elixir-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk-with-docker), so the only thing that I can think is that this has to be some sort of NGINX error.

I feel I'm a bit closer, and trying to route the localhost to the AWS EB endpoint is the right direction.

***EDIT:***

I've made a question on ServerFault as well, as they may be a more targeted community and have some ideas https://serverfault.com/questions/884036/how-do-i-modify-nginx-routing-on-elastic-beanstalk-aws-so-x-post.

Comment: Best of luck with this... Elastic Beanstalk scripts seem to really screw this up.  They will override your Nginx configs as they see fit.  Last time I had a deployment like this, it worked fine and then AWS changed something which broke my Nginx config.  You might be better off not using Elastic Beanstalk, sadly.  I do hope someone has a good answer for you though!

Comment: I just wish their NGINX worked out of the box, or they had a "push this button to get XXXXXX endpoints". You would think that would be step numero uno.

Comment: Yeah, agreed.  I think Elastic Beanstalk is meant for a different use case and type of developer... if you feel the need to fiddle with Nginx out front, they probably expect you to just write your own scripts, which is all Beanstalk is doing under the hood.  But, it sure would be useful if Beanstalk were a bit more flexible.

Comment: I'm not sure but every time that we deploy an update with `eb deploy` or other cli, I think that if I add some commands to publish a nginx config or create a directory or files, I need to put a command above to remove that before it. Otherwise our stack will fall off.  I have 
a doubt related with that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48831743/aws-beanstalk-nginx-killed-when-tried-to-add-new-environment