# ElasticBeanstalk `eb setenv` - application restart

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When running `eb setenv`, this fails to run the hooks in .ebextensions. In my .ebextensions I am removing the default nginx config and replacing it with a new config. It is crucial that this hook gets run everytime the app starts up so that nginx does not crash. Here is my .ebextensions/proxy.config file (I also attached it).

When I upload the zipped app, the hooks run as expected. It's only when restarting the app via the `eb` api that the file `/etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf` reappears

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong, or if this is a limitation of ElasticBeanstalk.

```
files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      upstream nodejs {
        server 127.0.0.1:8081;
        keepalive 256;
      }

      server {
        listen 8080;

        if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
          set $year $1;
          set $month $2;
          set $day $3;
          set $hour $4;
        }

        access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

        location ~* ^/(api) {
          proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
          proxy_set_header   Connection "";
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
          proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 10240;
        gzip_comp_level 4;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        location / {
          alias /var/app/current/public/;
          try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
      }

  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/97_kill_default_nginx.sh:
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      set -x
      rm -f /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#conf.d#* /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf
      initctl stop nginx || true
      initctl start nginx
```

Answer (score 1):

I eventually reread the [Platform Hooks docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platform-hooks.html) much closer and found the difference between `appdeploy` and `configdeploy`

> appdeploy — Scripts run during an application deployment. Elastic Beanstalk performs an application deployment when new instances are launched and when a client initiates a new version deployment.
>
> configdeploy — Scripts run when a client performs a configuration update that affects the software configuration on instance, for example, by setting environment properties or enabling log rotation to Amazon S3.

After reading these descriptions, it was clear to me that I needed to move alter my `proxy.config` file so that `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/97_kill_default_nginx.sh` becomes `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/post/97_kill_default_nginx.sh`. To be safe and ensure that this script runs when both launching a new version of the app, as well as updating an env variable, I copy/pasted it for BOTH `appdeploy` and `configdeploy`. So the final `proxy.config` looks like

```
files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      upstream nodejs {
        server 127.0.0.1:8081;
        keepalive 256;
      }

      server {
        listen 8080;

        if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
          set $year $1;
          set $month $2;
          set $day $3;
          set $hour $4;
        }

        access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

        location ~* ^/(api) {
          proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
          proxy_set_header   Connection "";
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
          proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 10240;
        gzip_comp_level 4;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        location / {
          alias /var/app/current/public/;
          try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
      }

  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/97_kill_default_nginx.sh:
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      set -x
      rm -f /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#conf.d#* /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf
      initctl stop nginx || true
      initctl start nginx

  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/post/97_kill_default_nginx.sh:
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      set -x
      rm -f /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#conf.d#* /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf
      initctl stop nginx || true
      initctl start nginx
```

A good way to debug this (and any hook scripts for that matter) would be to ssh onto the EC2 managed by beanstalk and create the file `touch /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf`. Then in a separate terminal window, run the `eb setenv` (or whatever command to restart the app). Then in the ssh'd window, once the `eb setenv` command completes, check the file was deleted `ls -l /etc/nginx/conf.d`

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting approach.  I followed the example posted by Amazon here:
[AWS example](https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/security-configuration/https-redirect/nodejs/https-redirect-nodejs.config), which suggested using container commands.

```
container_commands:
removeconfig:
    command: "rm -f /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#conf.d#00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf"
```

However, when updating the zipped file (same approach as you, I think), the config update always crashed.

I had to follow the approach outlined in this answer to get it working with container commands: [stackoverflow restart script help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50494492/9613104)

My postcongif deploy hook now looks like (and I use the container command):

```
  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/post/99_kill_default_nginx.sh:
 owner: root
 group: root
 mode: "000755"
 content: |
   #!/bin/bash -xe
   set -x
   echo "starting post config script"
   status=`/sbin/status nginx`
   if [[ -e "/etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf" ]];
    then
      echo "default config file exists - we should delete it"; fi
      rm -f /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf
      echo "restart nginx after deletion"
      if [[ $status = *"start/running"* ]]; then
        echo "stopping nginx..."
        stop nginx
        echo "starting nginx..."
        start nginx
      else
        echo "nginx is not running... starting it..."
        start nginx
      fi
    else
      echo "no default config file exists - no need to delete it"
    fi
```